# Android - App crashed due to unexpected signal 13 without cause

Tags: android

Literally no idea why it crashed, forgot what change I made last. I was trying to change my database to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` and I dont know if I changed some essential code without noticing.

```
04/06 10:59:13: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\Kontor\AndroidStudioProjects\Sales\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.sales.kontor.sales
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.sales.kontor.sales"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.sales.kontor.sales
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.sales.kontor.sales/com.sales.kontor.sales.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 25808 on device huawei-huawei_gra_l09-S7M0215902006571
E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sales.kontor.sales-2/lib/arm64
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.sales.kontor.sales, real application class is null.

              [ 04-06 10:59:16.884  2917: 2917 E/         ]
              process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sales.kontor.sales-2/lib/arm64
I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl

          [ 04-06 10:59:17.928  2917: 2917 E/         ]
          process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25808 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: check the location `/data/app/com.sales.kontor.sales-2/lib/arm64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uninstall the app and reinstall as the table you created previously wont be having the field ON DELETE CASCADE.

or

Try to clean the project and then again install it

Answer (score 0):

See little bit carefully in your log. You are trying to run the app with Instant Run. So, You can disable InstantRun and see if the problem persists or not.

For disable InstantRun:

> Goto - File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run
>   -> uncheck checkbox of Enable Instant run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy(default enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Change your apk file extension to `.zip` and extract it. check `lib\arm64` path for available all your `.so` files. Some time, some `.so` files available only for special CPU types.
You can filter your target cpu types in module gradle like this:

```
defaultConfig {

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```